# Cross-country binary data analysis

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, binary-data, odds-ratio, cross-section

We have cross-sectional data for 4 countries. Both dependent and independent variables are categorical.(binary data, in 'yes/no' form). Our analysis focuses on **comparison of independent variables** in these 4 countries. Our sample size is 7000 for first part of analysis and 3000 for second.

-Which models can we use apart from Logistic/Probit models? As the results do not seem reliable.

-Are odd ratios a better way of comparison than coefficients?

Comment: What do you mean by reliable? Do you mean the coefficients have large standard errors?